# RXJS 6 Doubts Chaining observables

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

i dont know the way to get the value of observable 2 inside the last map, here is an example

```
return observable1.pipe(
map((value1: value1) => {
 return observable2;
 }),
mergeMap((value2: value2) => {
 return observable3;
 }),
 map((value3: value3) => {
 // how can i get value 2 inside here?
 }),
 mapTo(null) 
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly sure what you are trying to accomplish, it's possible you may be approaching the problem the wrong way.  Never the less if you just need access to value2 then this should work for you.

```
return observable1.pipe(
  map((value1: any) => {
    return observable2;
  }),
  mergeMap((value2: any) => {
    // pass both value 2 and observe3 to the next operator
    return of({observable3, value2});       
  }),
  map((obs: any) => {
    console.log(obs.observable3);
    console.log(obs.value2);
    return obs.observable3;
    // how can i get value 2 inside here?
  }),
  mapTo(null)
);
```

Comment: may be im approuching the problem the wrong way, yes the way you are doing works fine, but i was searching for some resolution that doesnt nest pipes if it's possible

Comment: Ah okay, only way I can think of for that is to create a new observable with of() from the mergeMap().  Updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

If `observable2$` and `observable3$` can be run in parallel, you can use `combineLatest` to solve this problem

```javascript
   import {
     ...
     combineLatest,
   } from 'rxjs';

  observable1$.pipe(
    map(() => combineLatest(
      observable2$,
      observable3$
    )),
    mergeMap(([value2, value3]) => {
      return value3;
    }),
    mapTo(null)
  )
```

Note: there are 2 `combineLatest` functions, one from `rxjs`, one from `rxjs/operators`. This code use from `rxjs`

If `observable3$` run after `observable3$`, the solution is similar, with more 1 step to map data

```javascript
   import {
     ...,
     of,
     combineLatest,
   } from 'rxjs';

  observable1$.pipe(
    map(() => observable2$)
    mergeMap((value2) => combineLatest(
      of(value2),
      observable3$
    )),
    mergeMap(([value2, value3]) => {
      return value3;
    }),
    mapTo(null)
  )
```

Comment: I need the result of observable 2 to assign it after observable 3 , i dont want to run them in a parallel way, thanks for your answer!

Comment: I updated solution for your problem. It is simple, just wrap value2 with `of`, it will make value2 as stream, and combine with value3 to result

Comment: the combineLatest from rxjs isn't deprecated?

Comment: No, it's not. It still available in the API doc: https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/combineLatest